# Extract the data from Azure Devops Services (WIT Analytics) to Azure SQL Database using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

We have been working on large migration project which contains almost 50K Work Items including requirements, documents, Use Cases, Test Cases, Bugs, Issues etc. in our Azure Devops Services. As a BI Developer, we wanted to create some generic dashboards for all the teams across the organisation for the visibility and insights to take decisions. Initially, we used Power BI Advanced Functions(M Query etc.) to extract the data from WIT Analytics model and created datasets on Power BI Premium Service. Now, we want to push all our data directly to Azure SQL Database for data retaining and snapshots. There are different ways we can do that.

1. Power BI Advanced Functions, ODATA Feed(Not supported in ADF), REST API(Limitations on Number of Records)

Unfortunately, every way has it's disadvantages. What could be the best possible way to extract the data on hourly/daily basis from Azure Devops Service to Azure SQL Databases?

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: ODATA is supported in ADF

Answer (score 1):

You can use ODATA source in Azure data factory. See the tutorial in below document:

[Copy data from an OData source by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-odata)